# MongoDB $lookup replace a user_id field in object(the object will be in a array of objects) with a user document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, rust

I have a collection of tickets
the ticket has this scheme:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc5ea14bde4bfd53e824c8"
    },
    "number": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    },
    "creation_time": {
        "$date": "2021-12-17T09:55:45.857Z"
    },
    "modified_time": null,
    "title": "Fix ethernet ports",
    "description": null,
    "tags": [],
    "assigned_to": null,
    "created_by": {
        "$oid": "61bc5ea14bde4bfd53e824c7"
    },
    "status": "Opened",
    "solution": null,
    "priority": "Low",
    "confidentiality": "Public",
    "changes": [],
    "messages": [{
        "$oid": "61bc5ea14bde4bfd53e824c6"
    }, {
        "$oid": "61bc931ca1e7188973dec71b"
    }, {
        "$oid": "61bf3ef02f689cef7e2aeb1f"
    }],
    "last_activity": {
        "$date": "2021-12-17T09:55:45.857Z"
    },
    "hidden": false
}
```

I am able to with $lookup
query

```json
 $lookup: {
  from: 'messages',
  localField: 'messages',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'messages'
 }
```

which retrieves all the messages but now in the messages is field "author" and it contains id to a user document,
how can i replace in every message the author id with corresponding user document?

message scheme:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc5ea14bde4bfd53e824c6"
    },
    "time": {
        "$date": "2021-12-17T09:55:45.856Z"
    },
    "edited_time": null,
    "changes": [],
    "content": "sdsdsd",
    "author": {
        "$oid": "61bc5ea14bde4bfd53e824c7"
    }
}
```

user scheme:

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "61bc5ea14bde4bfd53e824c7"
    },
    "role": "Employee",
    "username": null,
    "first_name": "...",
    "last_name": "...",
    "email": "...",
    "token": "...",
    "solved_tickets": [],
    "reputation": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    }
}
```

I tried so many things but it always ended up not working, I am trying to do this for days, I think I am pretty dumb, I must have missed something important, feeling the imposter syndrome pretty hard rn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are nested lookups,
inside your lookup you can use the field `pipeline` to add an entire aggergation to the other document.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'messages', 
      'localField': 'messages', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'messages', 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$lookup': {
            'from': 'user', 
            'localField': 'author', 
            'foreignField': '_id', 
            'as': 'author'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Hey, thank you, that seems better but the field author is now array but it's empty
I made sure the user with the id that is in author exists

Comment: I used wrong name for the collection, thank you so much, this worked, you are amazing